# DOJO: find child

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here is the code:

```
dojo.query(subNav.navClass).forEach(function(node, index, arr){
        if(dojo.style(node, 'display') == 'block'){

           "NOW HOW WOULD I FIND CHILDREN????"

            });
        }
    });
```

By the way I just started working with DOJO, i am primarily working in jQuery.

So now that i have found node that has its display set to block, i want to preform something to its specific children, how would i preform query on children of the node that i just stopped on?

any clarification, suggestion? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     dojo.query('> li .secondary_nav_dropdown', node).style('display', 'none');
```

The second parameter specifies origin where the query should start from.

[Dojo query documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/query#queries-rooted-at-a-given-element)

Answer (score -1):

U can use array children and mapping like this:

```
dojo.map(node.children, function(child){
// work with child
})
```

Comment: This answer is misinformative... firstly, `dojo.map` doesn't make sense here; the way you're using it, you'd be far more interested in using `dojo.forEach`.  secondly, you probably meant `node.childNodes`, not `node.children` which appears to be Gecko-1.9 specific.

Comment: thank you guys, still. I found the answer by reading documentation fully. Silly me. Ended up posting this stuff prior dedicated extra time to read through. But still thank you for the input.